# where is AppCompatToggleButton in AndroidX?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-support-library, androidx

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatToggleButton), AppCompatToggleButton exists. I need to use this widget, but it does not exist in this package:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it. It is in 1.1.0-alpha02

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
```